# Java while loop never enters loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm writing a video poker in java, and I need to ask the player if the want to remove any cards from their hand. I wrote a `while` loop for that, but it is not working the way it's supposed to right now. I'd appreciate if someone could send me in the right direction--I'm still new to java.. Thanks. (the `counter` is there so that the player doesn't remove more than 5 cards)

```
    String response = "y";
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("Remove any cards?");
    System.out.println("Enter y for 'yes' and n for 'no'");
    response = input.nextLine();
    while((response != "n") && (counter < 5))
    {

        System.out.println("Enter the number of a card to be removed (1-5)");
        int l = input.nextInt();
        p.removeCard(p.getHand().get(l-1));
        p.addCard(cards.deal());
        cards.incrementTop();
        counter ++;
        System.out.println("Card removed. More? Type 'yes' or 'no'");
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        if (answer == "no")
            {
                response = "n";
            }       
    }
```

Comment: What way *is* it working right now, and how does it differ from how it's "supposed" to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compare Strings using `!=` or `==`.

Use [`.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
while(!("n".equals(response)) && (counter < 5))
```

The same here too

```
if (answer == "no")
```

Other things to improve

- The user could write "no" the first time and how it's done right now it could not work

  - You ask to the user to write "no" but you check for "n"
- What about N? Y?
- What about nO? NO? (Hint: search `.equalsIgnoreCase()`)

Another hint for you: Use a boolean variable for `yes/no`, is better and more easy :)

Comment: Thanks! I always forget that about strings. But I don't understand why after asking if the player wants to remove more cards it doesn't wait for the answer and goes straight to the 1st line of the loop again. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the String.equals() method to compare strings. Your while loop should be

```
 while(( !response.equals( "n" )) && (counter < 5))
  {
       //do Something 
  }
```